# How to take out the props passing to Hoc function

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I write a `withHoc.js`, passing component and wrappedComponent:

```
export const withHoc = ( WrappedComponent, Component ) => class WithHoc extends Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <WrappedComponent>
        <Component>
      </WrappedComponent>
    )
  }
}
```

And Create another `withWrappedHoc.js` using styled-component:

```
const WrappedComponent = styled.div`
  ...
`
export const withWrappedHoc = (Component) => 
  withComponent(Component, WrappedComponent )
```

The `withWrappedHoc` are the same as `withHoc`, except it replace the WrappedComponent with my own custom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be much clear to use curry to pattern these hoc functions as this:

```
export const withHoc = ( WrappedComponent ) => (Component) => class WithHoc extends Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <WrappedComponent>
        <Component>
      </WrappedComponent>
    )
  }
};


const WrappedComponent = styled.div`
  ...
` 
export const withWrappedHoc = withhoc(WrappedComponent);
```